# Large named.run file

Tags: bind

I'm having this large named.run file sitting in my server.

What I [find out](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/how-can-i-get-rid-large-named-run-files-255711.html) is that it is just a log and it is safe to delete it.

Some suggest to run logrotate on it, but I was wondering if it is possible to configure the max limit of the size or don't generate at all?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you might have started named in debug mode, which can cause large `named.run` files.  By default named saves debug information to `/var/named/named.run` file. You can stop writing to it by disabling debug mode.

To check that your `named` is running without the debug option:

```
ps -aux | grep named
```

You may get a response like this

```
named -d 3 -c /etc/named-master.conf
```

If the `-d` flag exists try to restart named without it and check again

With regards to the `named.run` file, it is safe to delete but you need to stop `named` first.

Other useful info:

```
rndc notrace  # will disable debug in bind
rndc reload   # will reopen file handles
```